# Java grade calculator. Im confused on this instruction

Tags: java

For an exercise, Im trying to complete a project that is a java grade calculator. One of my instructions was to create a class called "grade." The instructions said:   "The Grade class should have two constructors. The first one should accept no parameters and set the initial value of the number instance variable to zero. The second should accept an integer value and use it to set the initial value of the number instance variable." Im stumped on how to start.

Comment: Create a file called "Grade.java". It should start `public class Grade`. Then follow the instructions?

Comment: In a nutshell, you start by writing code. That said, there's undoubtedly something else that's confusing you, but you didn't say what it was. So what, exactly, is stumping you?

Comment: Well, not to sound obvious, but you'd start by creating a class.  Then adding two constructors to that class.  Then differentiating those constructors by the parameters they accept.  Etc.  Have you tried anything?  If where you're stuck is on how to write any Java code at all then it sounds like what you're looking for are introductory tutorials on Java.

Comment: I wasnt sure how to code the constructors

Answer (score 2):

Although not very knowledgeable in java, it should go like this.

In Grade.java:

```
public class Grade{
   public int grade = 0;
   public Grade(){
      /// something
      grade = 0;
   }

   public Grade(int something){
     //something
     grade=something;
   }
}
```

In Main.java

```
class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Grade g = new Grade(100);
     System.out.println(g.grade);
   }
}
```